# Call function on class with elements that has certain 'data-*'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say I have the following html:

```
<img onclick="showStruct(this)" class="expand" src="Images/Plus.png" data-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
<img onclick="showStruct(this)" class="expand" src="Images/Plus.png" data-hidden="false" style="display: inline;">
<img onclick="showStruct(this)" class="expand" src="Images/Plus.png" data-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
```

If elements are hidden, I store `true` in `data-hidden` field, because I will have to hide all elements simultaneously and by storing the "state" in `data-hidden` field, I make sure I know which ones to show again.
I.e.:

```
<img onclick="showStruct(this)" class="expand" src="Images/Plus.png" data-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
<img onclick="showStruct(this)" class="expand" src="Images/Plus.png" data-hidden="false" style="display: none;">
<img onclick="showStruct(this)" class="expand" src="Images/Plus.png" data-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
```

What I am trying to do is, by using jquery, set `display: inline;` only for the elements with `data-hidden: 'false'`?

What I have (which works):

```
$(".expanded").each
    (function() {
        if($(this).attr('data-hidden')=='false'){
            $('.expanded').show();
        }
    });
```

And my question is, is there a better (more efficient) way or this is the only way to do it?

Comment: *"What I have (which works):"* What you have will show **all** elements with the class `expanded` if **any** of them has `data-hidden=false`, which doesn't seem likely to be what you want.

Comment: Arun's solution is the correct one, but just as a side-note, jQuery also das a [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function to use `data('hidden')` instead of `attr('data-hidden')`.

Comment: @IngoBürk Thanks! Wasn't aware of that. @T.J. Crowder, Are you sure? I am using it right now and it works only if the element's `data-hidden=false`.

Comment: @sPaz: I'm sure. The code `$('.expanded').show();`, if executed, will show all of the elements matching `.expanded`. Side note: If you use the `data` function (and there's **no** reason to here), be sure you read the documentation for it *very carefully*. It has more than one really surprising behavior.

Comment: Yes, what @T.J.Crowder says is correct. If any `data-hidden` is `false` your code will call `show()` on all elements with class `.expanded`, not just the one that has `data-hidden` set to `false`.

Comment: Here's a fiddle showing it: http://jsfiddle.net/R3u3A/1/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I won't be using `data` function here but I will keep in mind to read the documentation. And after looking at the function again, yes I think it would `show()` all elements. It should've been `$($(this)).show();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('.expanded[data-hidden="false"]').show()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DUbh8/)

Comment: Seems efficient enough! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(".expanded").filter(function(){
   return $(this).data('hidden') == 'false';
}).show();
```

Comment: There's no need to reinvent this wheel, we already have [a perfectly good one](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just wanted to display a different solution. :)